# Why does my Fedders A/C run continuously with the energy savings feature turned on?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning

I have a Fedders A6Q08F2A. When I have the Energy Saver on, it will run continuously unless I turn the temperature up to 85 and then it starts cycling on and off. The temperature in the room is 75. Any thoughts?

Comment: Welcome. Please don't YELL AT US.

Comment: Does the compressor run continously or just the circulating fan?

Comment: Both run continuously unless I raise the temperature to 85. Then it cycles on and off.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your A/C is too small to adequately cool your space, and crippling it with the energy saver just makes it worse.

The "energy saver" feature on an A/C unit likely just lowers the cooling rate so that the instantaneous power draw is lower.  Unfortunately, for a machine like an air conditioner that works on a "do X until Y is satisfied" basis, it just lengthens the amount of time it takes to hit the setpoint.  In your case, it seems to be never reaching the setpoint, causing it to run continously.

Your options would be to

- Raise the setpoint (which you already did and noted that it did eventually reach)
- Turn off the Energy Saver
- Make the conditioned area smaller by closing doors/curtains, etc.

It's a lot like the "Eco" mode on a lot of cars that simply reduces power, causing the driver to just accelerate for longer, ultimately wasting more fuel overall.